# How to combine two arrays into one object so that the values of the first array are keys, and the values of the second array are values

Tags: javascript

Two objects are given
const en = ["mon",  "tue",  "wed",  "thu",  "fri",  "sat",  "sun"];
const de = ["montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"];

It is necessary to combine these 2 arrays into one object so that the values of the first array are keys, and the values of the second array are values.
How to do it?

Comment: Hi. 1) Those are arrays. 2) Can't you simply write that object out? It would only have seven properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const 
  en = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"],
  de = ["montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"],
  result = Object.fromEntries(en.map((k, i) => [k, de[i]]));

console.log(result);
```

You can *also* [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) one of the arrays into the desired object.

```js
const 
  en = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"],
  de = ["montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"],
  result = en.reduce((acc, k, i) => ({ ...acc, [k]: de[i] }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using map, easy to understand:

```js
const en = ["mon",  "tue",  "wed",  "thu",  "fri",  "sat",  "sun"];
const de = ["montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"];
let result = {};

en.map((item, index) => result[item] = de[index])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: why map, if you do not use the new array?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over over the first array and collect the elements of the second at th e matching index:

```js
   const en = ["mon",  "tue",  "wed",  "thu",  "fri",  "sat",  "sun"];
   const de = ["montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"];
   let dict={}
 ;

   en.forEach ( (px, pn) => { dict[px] = de[pn]; });

   console.log(dict);
```